# Jquery document ready

Tags: jquery

In my web application when i click on a link i load some information using      $getJSON();
All this works fine but the loaded list doesn't work using the same script

this is my jQuery code

```
    function loadEspaces() {
    $(".monEspace").click(function(event) {
    //alert(event.target.id);
    $.getJSON("sousEspaces", {
    idEspaceParent : event.target.id,
    ajax : "true"
    }, function(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
    $("#shuffle-grid").animate( { "opacity": "remove"} , 1000 );
    }
    var html = "";
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    html += "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 task shuffle-item  filtered' data-date-due='2015-11-28' data-priority='3' style='visibility:  visible; transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out; -webkit- transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;'>"+
    "<div class='panel panel-default'>"
    +"<div class='panel-heading'>"
    +"<div class='panel-toolbar text-left'>"
    +"<span class='checkbox custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-inverse'> <input type='checkbox' name='customcheckbox1' id='customcheckbox1'> <label for='customcheckbox1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>"
    +"</span>"
    +"</div>"
    +"<h3 class='panel-title ellipsis' style='width: 100%;'>"
    +"<a href='#' class='monEspace' id='"+data[index].idEspace+"'>"+data[index].nomEspace+"</a>"
    +"</h3>"
    +"</div>"
    +"<div class='panel-body'>"
    +"<div class='row mb15'>"
    +"<div class='col-xs-12'>"
    +"<span class='text-muted'>Nom : </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>"+data[index].nomEspace+"</strong>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</div>"
    +"<div class='row mb15'>"
    +"<div class='col-xs-12'>"
    +"<span class='text-muted'>Description : </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>"+data[index].descriptionEspace+"</strong>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</div>"
    +"<div class='row'>"
    +"<div class='col-xs-6'>"
    +"<span class='text-muted'>Partage : </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
    +"<c:if test='"+data[index].partage+"'>"
    +"<span class='badge badge-success'>Partage</span>"
    +"</c:if>"
    +"<c:if test='!"+data[index].partage+"'>"
    +"<span class='badge badge-warning'>Non partage</span>"
    +"</c:if>"
    +"</div>"
    +"<div class='col-xs-6'>"
    +"<span class='ico-calendar3'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='text-muted'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>"+data[index].dateCreation+"</strong>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</div>"
    +"<div class='panel-footer'>"
    +"<ul class='list-table'>"
    +"<li>"
    +"<div class='img-group img-group-stack'>"
    +"<img src='/elearning/resources/image/avatar/avatar2.jpg' class='img-circle' alt='' title='Ori Duke'> <span class='more img-circle'>5</span>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</li>"
    +"<li class='text-right'>"
    +"<div class='img-group img-group-stack'>"
    +"<img src='/elearning/resources/image/avatar/avatar2.jpg' class='img-circle' alt='' title='Ori Duke'> <span class='more img-circle'>5</span>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</li>"
    +"</ul>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</div>"
    +"</div>";
    }
    $("#shuffle-grid").html(html);
    });
    });
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadEspaces();
});
```

Any help please

Comment: What doesn't work???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery triggers don't apply automatically to the dynamically added elements. For such case you must set trigger on container of newly added elements (`#shuffle-grid` in this example):

```
$('#shuffle-grid').on('click', '.monEspace', function(e) {
    // move code from $(".monEspace").click(function(event) here    
});
```

This is from [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on()**. To ensure
>   the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the
>   elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document
>   ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event
>   handlers.
>
> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 1):

In this case jquery .on() must be used which helps in attaching event to the element which are dynamically added..

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

The majority of browser events propagate, from the deepest, innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur all the way up to the body and the document element. It is therefore general practice to attach the event to document element which is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML. So the code should look like this for the list to work.

```
$(document).on('click', ".monEspace", callbackFunc)
```

Here callbackFunc is not called when the event occurs directly on the document (bound element), but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Good article: [Jquery Event Attachment through .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)